# Extracting a part of Document using StaxParser

Tags: java, xml, parsing, stax

I have an XML of the format.

```
<Person>
<firstName>Paul</firstName>
<lastName>Nibin</lastName>

<personalAttributes>
    <id>11021231</id>
    <rep>7</rep>

    ...
</personalAttributes>
<eyeColour>Brown</eyeColour>
</Person>
```

I am using Stax parsing to parse the XML and create a POJO.

and corresponding POJO is,

```
class Person
{
String firstName;
String lastName;

Document personalAttribute;

String eyeColour;
    ....

}
```

In this document, the personalAttributes element itself is a well formed document. I want to extract the personalAttributes as a Document/String itself. And continue to parse other elements.

Is it possible to do that using Stax parser?